# Como fazer union all em LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Preciso executar o comando abaixo usando `Linq`:

```
SELECT cnes, cmp, cbo, profNome, pa, sum(quant) total FROM bpai
group by pa
union all
select cnes, cmp, cbo, profissional, pa, sum(quant) total from bpac
group by pa
```

Todos os campos são `string` exceto o campo `quant` utilizado para somar.

Comment: Tem que usar o `Contat` que é o Equivalente ao `UNION ALL`. Pergunta do SO-EN [How to use union all in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360518/how-to-use-union-all-in-linq)

Comment: Me parece que vai ficar algo parecido com isto `var result =
(SELECT cnes, cmp, cbo, profNome, pa, sum(quant) total FROM bpai
group by pa).CONCAT(
select cnes, cmp, cbo, profissional, pa, sum(quant) total from bpac
group by pa);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o método `Concat`.

Perceba que este método obriga que os tipos de entrada sejam os mesmos. Se não existe nenhum contrato entre as classes `bpai` e `bpac` será necessário aquele `Select` declarando todos os campos que serão usados porque, dessa forma, serão criados novos tipos anônimos e, como eles têm **exatamente** os mesmos campos, eles terão o mesmo tipo.

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYEhrK)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tabela1 = new [] { new bpai { cnes = "A", pa = "1",  quant = 2 }, 
                               new bpai { cnes = "B", pa = "1",  quant = 4 }, 
                               new bpai { cnes = "C", pa = "2",  quant = 80 } };

        var tabela2 = new [] { new bpac { cnes = "A", pa = "1", quant = 2 }, 
                               new bpac { cnes = "B", pa = "1", quant = 4 }, 
                               new bpac { cnes = "C", pa = "2",  quant = 80 } };

        var union = tabela1.Select(a => new { a.cnes, a.pa, a.quant })
                    .Concat(tabela2.Select(b => new { b.cnes, b.pa, b.quant }))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.pa)
                    .Select(gp => new
                    {
                        Pa = gp.Key,
                        Total = gp.Sum(x => x.quant),
                        Itens = gp.ToList()
                    });

        foreach(var u in union)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Pa: { u.Pa } - Total: {u.Total}" +
                              $"Qtd Itens: { u.Itens.Count }");

            foreach(var i in u.Itens)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{i.cnes}");
            }
        }
    }
}

class bpai {
    public string cnes;
    public int quant;
    public string pa;
}

class bpac {
    public string cnes;
    public int quant;
    public string pa;
}
```